# Multiple instance of angular directive will return different value. Then how to get all the value in single event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the problem where i created a custom directive in which i created a text box. And i am using this multiple time on a template. The problem is that as i change on one text box i want to get the value of all field (or directives)

```
<mydirective type="text" name="x" />
<mydirective type="text" name="y" />
```

Here is the directive view template

```
<div><input type="text" name="sender" ng-model="cstmfld" value="" ng-change="sendResponse()" /></div>

<script>
 angular.module('myApp').directive('mydirective', function(){
     return {
       restrict: 'EA',
       replace: true,
       transclude: true,
       scope: {
        label: '@',
        input: '=',
        currencyList: '=',
        fieldModel:'='
       },
       templateUrl: 'views/field.html',
       controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $http){
          $scope.sendResponse = function(){
             //do something so i get both filed value
          }
       }
    }
 });
</script>
```

Do i making any mistake or is it possible

Comment: You mean to say if you change in one directive changes will reflect in all directives?

Comment: no the other field has some value and i wanted to calculate that with change of one value . I made it with a global variable but i want some dynamic solution

Comment: can you make a plunker and explain little more?